# How to unbundle a git bundle?

Tags: git, bundle, git-bundle

I just received a Git bundle via email. How do I unbundle it in order to read it? I am having trouble using the unbundle command.  I have tried

```
git unbundle *bundle name*
```

but that gives me just a weird code

```
eae0b00697e53cd87c871143051673f3ee413148
```

and refs/heads/master

Comment: We need more information to help you. For example, what is the "weird code"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I am having trouble using the unbundle command.

You are not supposed to run this command at all.

> I just received a Git bundle via email. How do I unbundle it in order to read it?

This is described in [the `git bundle` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bundle.html):

> #### EXAMPLE
>
> Assume you want to transfer the history from a repository R1 on machine A to another repository R2 on machine B. For whatever reason, direct connection between A and B is not allowed, but we can move data from A to B via some mechanism (CD, email, etc.). We want to update R2 with development made on the branch master in R1.
>
> To bootstrap the process, you can first create a bundle that does not have any basis. You can use a tag to remember up to what commit you last processed, in order to make it easy to later update the other repository with an incremental bundle:
>
> ```
> machineA$ cd R1
> machineA$ git bundle create file.bundle master
> machineA$ git tag -f lastR2bundle master
> ```
>
> Then you transfer file.bundle to the target machine B. Because this bundle does not require any existing object to be extracted, you can create a new repository on machine B by cloning from it:
>
> ```
> machineB$ git clone -b master /home/me/tmp/file.bundle R2
> ```
>
> This will define a remote called "origin" in the resulting repository that lets you fetch and pull from the bundle. The $GIT_DIR/config file in R2 will have an entry like this:
>
> ```
> [remote "origin"]
>     url = /home/me/tmp/file.bundle
>     fetch = refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
> ```

See the rest of the documentation for the rest of the instructions.  Note that *you* are "machine B" in this example; someone else, on machine A, has done the first few steps.  (Did they do them correctly?  I don't know; do you?)